# Why is the new CAPTCHA troubling me from posting questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, login

Frustrating! The new CAPTCHA  really begger's description. First, they want to type a number for verification, then they ask to copy a big code and to paste it. Then what?? Nothing happens! 2 minuites within had I pasted it. But nothing happens then; the page remains same;-(

I have been thus able to post nothing for the past 2 days! Previously it didn't happen. Just type a number and then pressing **verify** button, your quo/ans is posted.  But what's going on now? There is no **verify** button in the 2nd page. So, what should I do after posting the code?

What's causing the problem?? I am using Nokia 2700c and my browser is Opera; **does using this outdated mobile a sin?**

[N.B. : How did I post this question? Actually I also don't know. I have 2 browsers: Opera 7; the pre-installed Opera Mini. When I tried to post a quo on the former, it would ask for human verification and sometimes not. The same does happen for the later! God knows why it happens so:-|. Call it my luck or so, when I posted this question, I didn't get human verification. And so I could post this quo:-x ]

Comment: For what it's worth, Opera 12 (but not Opera Mini) [is supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161). Opera 7 is more than 10 years old, so you can't expect it to work on a modern website.

Comment: @David Z: Thanks sir! So, mine is obselete and thus the new CAPTCHA didn't work! Then I have to wait for the Christmas so that Santa may gift me a new smartphone! Thanks:-)

Comment: @David Z: Sir, can you tell why the previous CAPTCHA worked in my browsers that aren't supported??

Comment: Stuff works in unsupported browsers by sheer luck. There's no real rhyme or reason to it (except that the new one obviously utilizes a browser function the old one didn't).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Thanks,sir for the info! I had been here doing all the stuffs for past 11 months by mere luck!